# How Prepreg types and number of plies affect mechanical and thermal properties of the PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

What are advantages and disadvantages when using a single ply of 7628 type prepreg as compared to say 2 plies of 1080 or a similar prepreg. I'm primarily concerned about any mechanical and/or thermal differences (advantages/disadvantages) that might arise. Most most of the resources i found on the internet focus on the electrical performance which is fairly well understood.

I've read somewhere (cannot find now where) that higher fiber-glass content may affect the feature size (higher surface roughness) and the min hole size (higher fiberglass density tends to dull drill bits more often).

If I want to maintain a certain voltage isolation between two copper layers, is it better to go with 7628 (high glass content) or 2 x 1080 (higher resin content).

### Some usefull resources I used

Whitepapers at Isola group website ([link to website](https://www.isola-group.com/resources/white-papers/))

Shengyi materials ([link to website](http://www.syst.com.cn/en/product/list_132.aspx#pro))

### Disclamer

I'm not extensively familiar with this matter. The two links I posted above were two primary resources I used to inform myself about the matter. What I did see that few times my PCB manufacturer would use say 6 x 106 prepreg between the cores. This left me wondering why is that, and why not simply use thicker prepreg like 7628. Is this purely a convenience where the manufacturer used the prepreg material type that was available to him or there are some other reasons?

Comment: This is actually mostly a mechanical question. Look up composite lay ups on boats and wings. They talk all about fabric weight vs number of plies, and porosity and how they affect resin to fiber ratio and smoothness.

Comment: "*7628 (high glass content) or 2 x 1080 (higher resin content)*" I could be wrong but I think you have that backwards. Airplane guys specifically use more thin plies to reduce resin content ( and thus dead weight).

Comment: Well, I'm also wondering about thermal properties. There is a clear advantage of using higher resin content as it allows for better adhesion to the core, higher surface smoothness and better thickness control (more of the resin can leak out during pressing)

Comment: It is right, check Fig 5 and Fig 6 of this document https://www.isola-group.com/wp-content/uploads/Developments-in-Glass-Yarns-and-Fabric-Constructions.pdf

Comment: You don't need high resin content for smoothness and adhesion. You just use lighter, tighter woven plies.